# LZ4 and Zstd for Java

Tags: file, lossless-compression, lz4, zstd

Is there any Best Java Compression Library available for LZ4 and ZStd. I have tried with apache commons ( which is zstd-jni implementation)

```
            String fileURL = TestFileUtil.getFileURL(TestFileCategory.SMALL);
            String outputFileName = TestFileUtil.BASE_DIR+"/zstd-"+(Math.random()*10)+".x";
            System.out.println(Paths.get(fileURL));
            printFileInfo(fileURL);
            StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();          
            InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileURL));
            OutputStream fout = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(outputFileName));
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
            ZstdCompressorOutputStream zOut = new ZstdCompressorOutputStream(out);
            int buffersize = 1024*4;
            watch.mark();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
            int n = 0;
            while (-1 != (n = in.read(buffer))) {
                zOut.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
            zOut.close();
            in.close();
```

But this code doesnt work it throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/luben/zstd/ZstdOutputStream
    at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.zstandard.ZstdCompressorOutputStream.<init>(ZstdCompressorOutputStream.java:83)
    at com.zoho.test.testzstd.main(testzstd.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdOutputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

and for LZ4 I just replace ZStdCompressorOutputStream with

```
FramedLZ4CompressorOutputStream lzOut = new FramedLZ4CompressorOutputStream(out);
```

But it tooks almost 2hrs (not yet completed ) to compress 2.4GB (csv) file.
Is there anything wrong with the code? or anyother suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

For `zstd`, Java has @luben's zstd-jni :
https://github.com/luben/zstd-jni

If you prefer Java native, @martint has a complete port in Java (though with less features) at :
https://github.com/airlift/aircompressor/tree/master/src/main/java/io/airlift/compress/zstd

For LZ4, a common binding is : https://github.com/lz4/lz4-java ,
though if you prefer an implementation which is compatible with the `lz4` CLI, the [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/compress/compressors/lz4/package-summary.html) version is preferable.

These libraries generally cannot be swapped by just changing one invocation name. Refer to their documentations or examples in order to understand how they work.

Comment: Do you have any specific example of String compression using luben library? I am really finding it hard to get one. Tried this but it doesn't work: byte[] zstdBytes = Zstd.compress(payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        ZstdInputStream zstdInputStream= new ZstdInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zstdBytes));

Comment: Yep, that link is answered by me to my own question :) I was able to get over my problem. Thank you for taking time to respond to my question :thumbup

Comment: can i pls provide some code or post answer to this question, so we can understand in better way

Comment: how can I decompress this .7z file in custom file location

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.github.luben.zstd.Zstd;

public class ZSTD {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Zstd zstd = new Zstd();

        System.out.println("Default compress level：" + Zstd.defaultCompressionLevel());

        try {
            //1.File operation
            byte[] src = File2ByteArray.toByteArray("D:\\works\\ZSTD\\data\\data.bin1");
            src = File2ByteArray.toByteArray("D:\\works\\ZSTD\\data\\aa.txt.zst");
            
            byte[] des = new byte[src.length/4];
            
            System.out.println("src length" + src.length);
            
            Zstd.decompress(des, src);
            
            System.out.println( "result：" +new String(des) );
            
            //2

            String data = "ABC";
            byte[] strSrc = Zstd.compress(data.getBytes());

            //byte[] strDest = new byte[ strSrc.length ];
            byte[] strDest = new byte[strSrc.length/4];
            Zstd.decompress( strDest, strSrc );
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```